# printing json in readable format inside python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to prints json in readable form. I already checked previous threads and tried out.

using

```
JSON.stringify(response)
```

gives error:

```
NameError: name 'JSON' is not defined
```

Using

```
response = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
parsed = json.loads(response)
print json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

gives error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p6.py", line 15, in <module>
    parsed = json.loads(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 328, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: ``JSON.stringify`` is not even Python. It's javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You get

```
NameError: name 'JSON' is not defined
```

because the first snippet is in JavaScript, not in Python.

As to the second snippet, you are calling `json.loads()` twice:

```
response = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(url).read())  # calling once
parsed = json.loads(response)                      # calling twice
```

Just call it once (and ensure that what you get from the HTTP server is actually JSON).